# In python,I'm trying to multiply the two arrays in below sequence printing using with for loop or while loop

Tags: python, arrays

A = [a11 a12 a13 a14 ....a1000]

B = [b11 b12 b13 b14.... b1000]

Printing with multiply

print(a11*b11)
print(a11*b12)
print(a11*b13)
print(a11*b14)
.
.
.
.
.
Print(a11*b999)
Print(a11*b1000)

print(a12*b11)
print(a12*b12)
print(a12*b13)
print(a12*b14)
.
.
.
.
.
Print(a12*b999)
Print(a12*b1000)

print(a13*b11)
print(a13*b12)
print(a13*b13)
print(a13*b14)
.
.
.
.
.
Print(a13*b999)
Print(a13*b1000)
.
.
.
.
.
.
print(a1000*b11)
print(a1000*b12)
print(a1000*b13)
print(a1000*b14)
.
.
.
.
.
Print(a1000*b999)
Print(a1000*b1000)

Comment: and your problem is ?

Comment: A simple while loop with i< len(A) could be used instead. Print (A[i}*B[i]) if they are the same size.

Comment: Your 'lists' lack comma separation

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above operation with lists in python as following.The list can contain any number of items.I hope this answer your question.You can check the output of this code on [repel online python editor](https://repl.it/languages/python3)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

for first_list_number in a:
  for second_list_number in b:
    product = first_list_number * second_list_number
    print(product)
```